# Build a model that answers question from dataset using GPT3

Tags: nlp, nlp-question-answering, gpt-3

I am trying to build a chat bot, that given some text corpus, will answer questions when we ask something from that text. I have heard GPT3 is a beast and requires minimum training. Are there any links/ tutorial/github repo's that will help me get started with this?

Comment: It's okay if i have to make payments for API calls. I have seen projects online training GPT to learn write SQL statements

Comment: You should look for RASA, here is an example - https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa-demo

Comment: i believe its public now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, if you got a beta access to the [OpenAI GPT-3 API](https://beta.openai.com/) you're easily able to do so. In case you don't, you can apply for it - you should get accepted fairly quickly *(in my specific case it took about 24 hours)*.

Depending whether you look for speed or precision you should choose between Davinci, Cushman or Curie ([list of engines](https://beta.openai.com/docs/engines)), whereas Davinci is the best (precision-wise).

You can use the Playground to enter a text corpus and a question - here is an example:
[image: Example picture]
*I used `davinci-instruct-beta` with a temperature of `0.25` and response length of `10`. A pretty basic setup.*

For demonstration purposes, here is the API request made via **Python**. `response` returns *"Anna hates doing research the most."*

```
import openai

openai.api_key = 'KEY'

response = openai.Completion.create(
  engine="davinci-instruct-beta",
  prompt="Anna loves programming in Python and C++, though she absolutely despises doing research.\nWhat does Anna hate the most?\n\nAnna hates doing research the most.Example",
  temperature=0.25,
  max_tokens=10,
  top_p=1
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but for openAI is there an upper limit on length of corpus, like its 512 for Question answering using BERT?

Comment: @Nidutt As far as I’m aware the maximum length of completion is 2048 tokens which roughly translates to (depending on various factors) 8000 chars - though I’m not totally sure. Bear in mind that this is the upper limit.. ;)

Comment: Also note that these limitations do not apply to search & classification.